# No conection string named $MyConStringName could be found in the application config file. But it's there

Tags: c#, inheritance, connection-string, designer

I have some rare form heritage. I have a base generic form in one project.

In another one I have the sons. But since I need to design them and it seems that you can't design something that is inherating from a generic form I need to use some intermediat forms.

So I have the form that I use extending from the intermediat form. And the intermediate extends from the generic base.

The base:

```
namespace GestioBaseForanies
{
    public partial class frmGestioBaseForanea<T> : Form where T : class, TeActiu
```

The intermediate:

```
namespace GestioFillForanies.Intermediates
{
    public partial class InterUsuario : frmGestioBaseForanea<Entity.Usuari>
```

And the one that I use:

```
namespace GestioFillForanies
{
    public partial class Usuario : Intermediates.InterUsuario
```

So it worked with no problem, but then and aparently out of the blue the "Usuario" designer is unable to load and tells me that there is no conection string name "ContextES" on tha app.config.

[image]

The connection string name is the Entity Framework String. It's in the config file and I can build and run the program, but i can't design.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the code in your windows form that is trying to initialize a database connection. This will be most likely in your constructor in the form. Put any code that accesses the database inside the if statement so that it will not be executed when you open the designer.

```
        InitializeComponent();

        if (LicenseManager.UsageMode != LicenseUsageMode.Designtime)
        {
              // SQL/EF CODE HERE
        }
```